# WordPress not running on port 80

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have an Ubuntu 16 machine running docker and docker-compose
the docker-compose YML looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
 image: mysql:5.7
 volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abware
   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

wordpress:
 depends_on:
   - db
 image: wordpress:latest
 ports:
   - "8000:80"
 restart: always
 environment:
   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
db_data:
```

when I run: **docker-compose up -d**
it installs MySql+WP images and runs the containers and everything is just fine.
then, when I try to access my web site by navigating to: www.my-host.com:**8000**
it shows the WordPress website but when I navigate to the same URL with port **80** it's not working...
How do I make WordPress to work on the default port 80?

Comment: replace "8000:80" to "80:80" rebuild the container and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section:

```
ports:
  - "8000:80"
```

in the YML maps the host port `8000` to the container port `80`. Changing that to `80:80` and rebuilding the container (as mentioned by @[Kilan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464538/klian)) should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this `ports:
   - "8000:80"`

you mapped the port 8000 of your host on the port 80 of your container. It's normal if you can't navigate from your host with port 80.

Replace with `80:80`, but before this, be sure that this port is free on your host.